# Is it possible to recognize that a user is the same unauthenticated user in a subsequent session with guest access of federated identity?

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-appsync, federated-identity

Let's say a user makes a purchase. Is it somehow possible to detect that a user is the same person on a different device when using Cognito User pools with federated identities that allow guest access?

I don't want my users to have to provide an email address, but I want to know what is the most reliable way I can ensure they have the most access possible to any in app purchases they make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it seems not possible to do it.

The situation you described is like unauthenticated, so you will just get an identity id and that is always some random uuids to exchange for credentials.